# 'Recognize Text' option not visible in Visual Recognition Node

Tags: ocr, ibm-watson, node-red

I'm not able to see 'Recognize Text' option in 'Visual Recognition' Node in the Watson Node-Red pallet.
I'm using Visual Recognition v3 node. Please check attached screenshot.
I've check this on Windows PC as well as Raspberry Pi. But it's same on both.
Is there any other way to achieve OCR using Watson nodes in NODE-RED ?

[image: Visual Recognition Node]

Answer (score 0):

The OCR, text recognition methods of the visual recognition service was closed Sept 2019 - https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/visual-recognition?topic=visual-recognition-release-notes

The feature was removed from the Watson Node-RED Node soon after.